# How can I get a pop up on my site like Stack Overflow?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

When I hover over my username on the site it drops down a box.  I'm wanting to try and implement something similar can someone lead me in the direction of how to replicate this? Thanks!

Comment: do you want to know how to do it or complete code?

Comment: it should be pretty straight forward , i can guid you if you want

Comment: In which point of implementation are you stuck? It's always good to send example of your code. I can't see where is the problem from your current question. Some hints: css: "position: absolute", "z-index", jQuery: "hover", "toggle", "get".

Comment: Thanks guys I was just more confused on which direction to go in. Since I've had little experience in jquery and such... So I'm gonna look into everything given here and see what I come up with :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just the concept:

1. Listen for `mouseover` (and `mouseout`) events.
2. When the `mouseover` event is triggered, you create/show some HTML element that is positioned there using DOM manipulation.
3. You can get additional content (to show in that box) using AJAX.
4. When `mouseout` is triggered for the box/link, hide the element again.

You can use JQuery (or any other framework) to simplify a lot of that.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery have many plugins to implement popups.Watch here http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this jQuery plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Answer (score 1):

It should very easy follow the below steps

1) Make your html ready

2) Make it absolute positioned

3) Listen to jquery mouseover even ad mouseover event.

4) Get the offset value off parent elemet which is mouseover event

5) Get the left val and Top Val of the mosueover from Offset val.

6) Do a .show on the absolute div item and position it next to the parent elemet